# How to unite several tables in a one so the names of the columns became the row names?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transpose

for instance I have

```
SELECT customer_id, first_name || ', ' || last_name || ', ' || email as "customer's info" 
FROM customer
WHERE customer_id = 5
;

SELECT count(i.film_id) AS "num.of films rented" FROM payment p
JOIN rental r ON p.rental_id = r.rental_id
JOIN inventory i ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
WHERE r.rental_date >= ('2014-01-01'::date)
AND r.rental_date <= ('2017-05-03'::date)
AND p.customer_id = 5
;
```

I want in output

```
metric1              | metric2 
----------------------------
customer's info      | blalalalal
num.of films rented  | blalalalal
```

I try smth like, but nothing

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
SELECT first_name || ', ' || last_name || ', ' || email
FROM customer WHERE customer_id = 5,
SELECT count(i.film_id) FROM payment p
JOIN rental r ON p.rental_id = r.rental_id
JOIN inventory i ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
WHERE r.rental_date >= ('2014-01-01'::date) 
AND r.rental_date <= ('2017-05-03'::date)) 
AS ('fjfjf' TEXT, 'fjfjf' int );
```

Could you help me?
I dont know how to do it in postgress
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would UNION ALL the two queries together - but remember to CAST the count value as a string, as you need matching data types to UNION:

```
SELECT 
  'customer''s info'                               AS "name"
, first_name || ', ' || last_name || ', ' || email AS "value" 
FROM customer c
UNION ALL
  'num.of films rented'         AS "name"
, COUNT(i.film_id)::VARCHAR(5)  AS "value"
FROM payment p 
JOIN rental r ON p.rental_id = r.rental_id
JOIN inventory i ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
WHERE r.rental_date >= ('2014-01-01'::date)
AND r.rental_date <= ('2017-05-03'::date)
WHERE customer_id = 5
;
```

Comment: yes, with some small corrections it could be decision, thank U very much!

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me why `inventory` is in the second join.

```
SELECT 'customer''s info' as metric1,
       first_name || ', ' || last_name || ', ' || email as metric2
FROM customer
WHERE customer_id = 5
UNION ALL
SELECT 'num.of films rented' as metric1, count(i.film_id)::text AS metric2
FROM payment p JOIN
     rental r
     ON p.rental_id = r.rental_id
WHERE r.rental_date >= '2014-01-01'::date AND
      r.rental_date <= '2017-05-03'::date AND
      p.customer_id = 5;
```

You could also combine this into a single query if you are just trying to get the results in a single result set:

```
SELECT (first_name || ', ' || last_name || ', ' || email) as customer_info,
      count(i.film_id) as num_films
FROM payment p JOIN
     rental r
     ON p.rental_id = r.rental_id JOIN
     customer c
     ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
WHERE r.rental_date >= '2014-01-01'::date AND
      r.rental_date <= '2017-05-03'::date AND
      c.customer_id = 5
GROUP BY c.customer_id;
```

(This puts the values in one row with two columns.)  Using a subquery, the results can be easily unpivoted.